# Good way to do a personal project review - what questions to ask

Tags: evaluation

I'm a project engineer with a consultancy. My work includes planning but also chasing after  contractors to make sure they deliver what they are paid for, and to keep communication between us, customer and contractor. I guess this can be seen as project management.

I'm in a late phase of my first project in this role. I plan to write a journal (for me, not to share with boss/coworkers) with what went wrong and how to improve next time. This will focus on the process issues, not on the technical ones.

The obvious way to go about this is to ask myself these questions:

- What went wrong?
- What could have gone better?
- What should I try different the next time?

Are there other questions I should ask myself?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a 'Lessons Learned Log' and if you [Google this term](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=lessons%20learned%20log) you will find many definitions, discussions and even templates.